# Laravel 5.1: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fill()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get this line to work `$user->profile()->fill($input['profile'])->save();`

Following [much discussion](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/laracast/lessons_building_user_profiles/) and [failed attempts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/building-user-profile-methodnotallowedhttpexception?page=0)

**I need help filling an eloquent model**

Also had a probelm with guarding
http://laravel.io/forum/01-06-2016-massassignmentexception-ignoring-fillable-guarded-is-set
Which i overcame with `protected $guarded = ['id'];`

Profile model

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

User Model

```
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_id');
    }
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::with('profile')->findOrFail($id);

    $input = $request->all();


    if(is_null($user->profile)){
        $profile = new Profile($input['profile']);
        $user->profile()->save($profile);
    alert()->warning('New profile creation attempt!');

    }else{
        // $user->profile()->fill($input['profile'])->save();
        $user->profile->title = $input['profile']['title'];
        $user->profile->facebook_username = $input['profile']['facebook_username'];
        $user->profile->meetup_user_id = $input['profile']['meetup_user_id'];
        $user->profile->save();
        // dump($input['profile']['title']);
        // dump($user->profile->title);
        //Unless it fails silently like before.
    alert()->success('Profile Saved!');
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.users.edit', [$id]);
}
```

Notice how I am manually filling, this is not ideal obviously. [this is the result i am trying to achieve](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ProfilesController.php)

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, you want to fill profile Attributes in a single line,
did you try `fill()` method ??

try this way in your `else` section or whereever your want it, I hope that might help you

```
$profile = new Profile;
$profile->fill($input['profile']);
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Comment: I have updated my initial question. your response would create a new profile, and looks like that would work, however i am trying to update existing code. thanks for your input

Comment: now whats the problem? what is thing you are not getting ?

Comment: ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fill()``` at line ```$user->profile()->fill($input['profile'])->save();```

Comment: Remove `fill()` from your above mentioned code and do it like this `$user->profile()->save($input['profile']);`

Comment: FatalThrowableError in HasOneOrMany.php line 212:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in

Comment: try this `$user->profile->fill($input['profile'])->save();` let me know about